# In the event of an abrasion, do mast cells cause vasodilation or vascular constriction?

Tags: immune-system, inflammation

Or both? I am unsure as to what mast cells will do in the event of a wound either on the epidermis or the epithelial. I know they secrete factors that mediate vascular constriction / dilation, but I can't find information anywhere as to what they do in the area where the wound is located.

Based off my current understanding, this is what I think happens:
Wound. Mast cells release mediators that cause constriction around the area of the wound, but dilation further upstream to increase the delivery of essential leukocytes (white blood cells), plasma and red blood cells.
Any help is greatly appreciated!